# Validating calls within a method using Mockito or jUnit

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I'm working on some modifications to a DAO. The modifications included refactoring some code to keep a couple of methods from calling `.getResultsList()` multiple times. Instead, the results are cached to a `List` and all subsequent code works with that list making the code run more efficiently by only reaching out to the database once.

I was asked to create jUnit tests for the methods I modified to ensure that something like this won't happen again in the future. Is it possible for me to validate how many times a local variable inside a method has a function called on it using mockito?

I've seen several questions/forum posts on using `verify` to validate the number of calls made on a mocked object. But I don't actually have access to mock this object as it is being created inside the method any not being passed in.

Basically -

`myDao` has a class variable `EntityManager` called `em`, the `em.createNamedQuery()` function is stored to a `TypedQuery` variable `q`. This `q` is what .getResultsList was being called on multiple times.

In my jUnit test, is it possible to listen to what's happening inside the method I'm calling on my mocked Dao and make sure that `q.getResultsList` is only called once while the method is running?

**UPDATE**

`myDao` in my test class is configured using the `@Autowired` annotation like so:

```
@Autowired
MyDao myDao;
```

It is defined in the applicationContext.xml like so:

```
<bean id="myDao" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.mypackage.myDao"/>
</bean>
```

The method I'm calling is inside that DAO, so I call `myDao.myMethod(myVar);` Inside `myMethod` is the q variable I'm wanting to listen to. It's a local variable.

Comment: What objects are you mocking and what functionaloty does your test cover? Do you mock `EntityManager`, or use a real DB?

Comment: @axtavt I updated the question with more detail about how it's configured right now. I'm trying to figure out a way to build a test without having to change all the previously written test to create new mocked objects. All the other tests right now are simply using `myDao` and `asserts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are mocking myDao then you aren't going to be able to validate code within myDao.

To test this you need a test for the myDao class. In that unit test you can mock `EntityManager` and have `createNamedQuery` return a mocked query.  Then you can use mockito's `verify` and `times(1)` to verify that `getResultsList()` was only called once on the mocked query.

Comment: I was really afraid that was the answer, I was hoping one of the SO gurus would throw out some miraculous way to handle my issue.

Comment: Or just `verify`.  The default verification mode is `times(1)`, so you never need to write `times(1)`.